# Force resolve a dependency conflict apt

Tags: apt, dependencies

```
# apt-get install -reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried the common fixes already.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -f install libcheese7
```

(returns 'libcheese7 is already at the latest version)

I got creative

```
sudo apt-get -f -reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

I tried purging the utopic Hardware Enablement stack, including all xorg packages marked with utopic. I removed all kernels but the 3.13 kernel from 14.04 and the latest kernel on my system 3.19.0-26-generic

Backstory:
My original issue is that my keyboard/touchpad dont always initialize during the lightdm handoff. I believe I attributed this to Xorg >1.10.1
I tried GDM and the issue persists, force reinstalling the input package solves the issue for a short while.

clean make no changes as well.

Can you please help me fix these dependencies from butting heads? Or even better help me get to the bottom of this nasty xorg bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the dependencies: log off from the GUI and switch to a console (Ctrl+Alt+F2). Then logon and remove the packages with unmet dependencies:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove gnome-control-center unity-control-center`

Then check /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*. Remove any repository other than the official ones for your ubuntu version.

Then do `sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`. If this fails keep removing offending packages (but keep notes which packages you removed) until this command succeeds.

Finally reinstall the packages you removed:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center unity-control-center`

The last command will pick the correct packages from the correct repos and may install additional dependency.